# Deleting Information from Parse Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, backend

I am buiding an app that allows users to see content in an app as well as add information to a Parse database and remove information.

In my Parse core, I have a class called "information", with columns called "title" and "detail".

I displaying the data in a table view using two arrays : titleArray and detailArray.

This is how I reload my information however it appears to fail when deleting the last item in a tableView.

```
func reloadData () {




    var query = PFQuery(className:"information")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            self.titleArray.removeAll()
            self.detailArray.removeAll()


            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {


                    if let stringTitle = object.objectForKey("title") as? String {

                        self.titleArray.append(stringTitle)


                        if let stringDetail = object.objectForKey("detail") as? String {
                            self.detailArray.append(stringDetail)


                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }
                    }

                }


            } else {

                var errorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to Retrieve Data", message: ("Error: \(error!)"), preferredStyle: .Alert)

                errorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)





            }
        }


    }


}
```

If I open another view controller in the application then go back, everything works fine, but if I run the viewDidLoad method it still has errors.

Please help me out! I will be very grateful.

Comment: are you getting objects back...?

Comment: Where is the problem its not deleting from tableView or its not deleting from parse...?

Comment: if anything i think you should pass that row as parameter

Comment: @C_X It's not deleting from Parse. The tableView is fine

Comment: @Lamar Sounds good. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reload tableView after the success of deletion and delete items also from your datasource

```
objectToDelete.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {
(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
 if (success) {
  // Force a reload of the table — update your datasource first
  titleArray.removeAtIndex(row)
  detailArray.removeAtIndex(row)
  self.reloadData()
} else {
 // There was a problem, check error
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` doesn't return objects. Did you check that this method returns objects to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
func deleteInformation (row:Int) {
var query = PFQuery(className:"information")
 query.whereKey("title", equalTo: titleArray[row])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {         
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {       
            for object in objects {                 
               object.deleteInBackground()
              }
            }
             self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
         }
       }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
return true
 }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
    row = Int(indexPath.row)
    deleteInformation(row)


}
```

}

Comment: i did not quite understand what you said

Comment: first did the code work.. then what is the message you get from the crash

Comment: maybe its because there is no more object into parse

Comment: i mean you should check parse and see if you have no object or if the object count is equal to zero

Comment: Ok, so when I delete the last item, it is removed from Parse but not from the tableView and when I try again it crashes. Is there something wrong in my reloadData method?

Comment: did you check parse page and see if you have object into the class where you are querying data from

Comment: Yes, I have found something strange. If I open another view controller in the application then go back, everything works fine, but if I run the viewDidLoad method it still has errors.

Comment: what you should do is to put more data into parse and try to delete them into you app

Comment: It deletes everything I set it to delete but the app doesn't know that and still thinks its there.

Comment: so you need to clean the array before you query new data into it

Comment: I used titleArray.removeAl( ) and detailArray.removeAll( ), please see my post.

Comment: place it before you do the query